# Should I call Axios in each component on a page or multiple times on the parent page for each component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm looking to understand what is the best practice when it comes to utilizing Axios to fetch data from Node.js. I have multiple graphs, cards and other components on the given page and am trying to understand if I should be calling Axios on the parent page for each component and passing the values as props to the component or rather call Axios and the data in each component itself.

Trying to understand what is seen as best practice.

From my understanding it is better to let each component be self standing (i.e. call its own data from the DB) rather than once on the page.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is used only in a sub-component, there is no need to query it one level above, do it in the component itself for the sake of encapsulation: it will allow you to not leave behind useless axios code should you remove the sub-component later.

If the data is shared by multiple components, do the query once and pass it to every child that needs it.

N.B. What is a common practice however, is to have a component that is purely "presentational" (with no logic, only receiving props), and a parent component that does the query (and maybe some other logic) and passes the result as props to the presentational one. It allows to re-use the graphical layout of the presentational component with different input data somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. But what to do if the components are all cards that follow the same design but display different data results? Do you pass a props to tell it what axios function to call and then have an external js file with multiple axios functions? Otherwise you need a card per component calling a specific axios function in the card which would be overkill and impossible to maintain.

Comment: It should be a single component for the card, and one wrapper for each request. You can pass a function to the wrapper component that does the request, though, as you suggest, that's perfectly legit. Then you only have 2 components to maintain.

Comment: That said, if they are all displayed at the same time, I would not be shocked to see a single wrapper doing all the requests async, and passing every new data as a prop to a card. Just as if all the data came from a single API call, after all. Whatever makes the code simpler is the way to go.

Comment: Do you by any chance know of any examples that I can investigate/learn from? Some code that describes the above. Thanks

Comment: @Elad Maybe this one: https://gist.github.com/chantastic/fc9e3853464dffdb1e3c from a Dan Abramov blog post (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have a layer between components and axios (a class / function that wraps axios for example).

Then, each components will call that class and the class will call axios.
By doing this, you can let each component fetch its own data.

Then you can add a logic so that if 2 components try to fetch the same data, you will cache it and only fetch it once.

By doing this, you keep each component self sufficient, and you reduce the number of calls to the server

Comment: Thanks you. I love the idea of caching the data when already called. Do you by any chance have a reference link to something like this?

Comment: you can look up "memoization" in javascript, there are npm packages that does it automatically, you just wrap your function, and if the function is called 2 times with the same parameters, it will only execute once.

Comment: React has a `useMemo` hook that does just this!